# Short console app to upload pdf file to d365?

Tags: c#, microsoft-dynamics

I wrote an easy console app to read a file and upload it to d365 via api. The files are PDFs.

I get still an error when I read the pdf file with a a filestream:

`ReadTimeout = 'filestream.ReadTimeout'` are throwing a `'System.InvalidOperationException'`.

After many hours of research, I have no idea why I cannot read the PDF file.

Here is my source code:

```
using (var filestream = File.OpenRead($"C:\\test\\test.pdf"))
{
    var length = filestream.Length.ToString();
    var streamContent = new StreamContent(filestream);
    streamContent.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
    streamContent.Headers.Add("Content-Length", length);

    var _application = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                           .Create(appid)
                           .WithClientSecret(clientsecret)
                           .WithAuthority(new Uri($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/aadid"))
                           .Build();

    var authResult = _application.AcquireTokenForClient(new[] { $"orgname.crm4.dynamics.com/.default" })
                                 .ExecuteAsync().ConfigureAwait(true);

    var temp = Task.Run(async () => { return await authResult; });
    temp.Wait();

    var token = temp.Result;

    using (var req = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("PATCH"), url))
    {
        req.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.AccessToken);
        req.Content = streamContent;
        //req.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
        req.Content.Headers.Add("x-ms-file-name", nameCleared + ".pdf");
        HttpClient Client = new HttpClient();

        using (var response = Client.SendAsync(req))
        {
            response.Wait();
            response.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: soory the erro still cums in the file.openread(<path>)

Comment: Are there any more details on that error? Does the `InvalidOperationException` possibly contain *inner exceptions* that would explain in more detail what the problem is?

Comment: no nomore exceptions this is the only one i get...

Comment: But there should *at least* be a message for that exception, no? You don't typically get "empty" exceptions without even a message telling you what the cause is ...